RVI does not catch deforestation : hypothesis
I'm actually working on a deforestation mapping in Papua. I'm trying to use NDVI (with Sentinel 2) and RVI here is presented a time series analysis of the two signal on a deforestation :

The RVI signal does not capture the deforestation and I don't have idea why? Your hypothesis are welcome. I already checked my code and the RVI is build properly (here is the link to my code : https://code.earthengine.google.com/efb1a1b76ec9434f4c98041b72cdd922)

I'd say because the volume scattering of the canopies is similar to the volume scattering of burnt surfaces at the ground. Also some of the stems and branches could have remained in these areas.
C-band of Sentinel-1 has a wavelength of around 5 cm which is most sensitive to objects of similar size/scale.
If you wanted to map deforestation by radar you would need L-band which is more sensitive to changes of larger structures and is used in most SAR-based deforestation studies.
This article confirms that S1 backscatter barely differs between forested and logged areas. https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/10/8/1250
